# Angularjs: How to inject dependency from resolve routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, routes, dependencies, code-injection, resolve

I have a problem injecting resolve parameters from the routing into the controller. I'm setting the resolve value to an object `{name: 'Banner', slug: 'banner'}`, but I get an error.

App.js

```
var app = angular.module('CMS', ['fields', 'ngRoute']);

app.controller('ModuleController', ['$http', 'properties',
  function($http, properties) {
    var module = this;
    module.properties = properties;

    if (module.properties.slug.length) {
      $http.get(module.properties.slug + '.php').success(function(data) {
        module.list = data;
      });
    }
  }
]);

app.controller('HomeController', function() {});

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  // route for the banner page
  .when('/banner1', {
    templateUrl: 'banner1.php',
    controller: 'ModuleController',
    resolve: {
      properties: function() {
        return { name: 'Banner', slug: 'banner' };
      }
    }
  })
  .when('/home', {
    templateUrl: 'home.php',
    controller: 'HomeController'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/home'
  });
});
```

Error:

```
 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$injector/unpr?p0=propertiesProvider%20%3C-%20properties%20%3C-%20ModuleController
    at Error (native)
    at http://modelo2.desenvolvimento.com/adm/js/angular/angular.min.js:6:417
    at http://modelo2.desenvolvimento.com/adm/js/angular/angular.min.js:38:7
    at Object.d [as get] (http://modelo2.desenvolvimento.com/adm/js/angular/angular.min.js:36:13)
    at http://modelo2.desenvolvimento.com/adm/js/angular/angular.min.js:38:81
    at d (http://modelo2.desenvolvimento.com/adm/js/angular/angular.min.js:36:13)
    at Object.e [as invoke] (http://modelo2.desenvolvimento.com/adm/js/angular/angular.min.js:36:283)
    at $get.w.instance (http://modelo2.desenvolvimento.com/adm/js/angular/angular.min.js:75:451)
    at http://modelo2.desenvolvimento.com/adm/js/angular/angular.min.js:58:476
    at s (http://modelo2.desenvolvimento.com/adm/js/angular/angular.min.js:7:408) <div ng-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

Comment: Did you know that when you use non-minified version of Angular you get more descriptive error messages? Try it next time

Comment: I'm guessing it is because you are using `ng-controller="ModuleController"` in `/banner1.php`

Comment: It was the ng-controller on banner1.php. Thanks @NewDev!

Comment: I answered it more comprehensively as a proper answer

Comment: How to resolve? I have the same problem, in resolve I have data, but in controller is not

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ngRoute` supports injection of resolved variables to the controller, which is useful for cross-cutting concerns of the app, like authentication or configuration of the app.

The downside is that the controller can **only** be instantiated with these parameters available to be injected, which means that either you instantiate your controller manually (with `$controller`), which almost never the case, or with `ngRoute` with resolve. What you cannot do with such a controller is instantiate it with `ng-controller` or in any other location where the injected parameters are not available.

This error indicates that in addition to having defined the controller on the route, you also have the controller defined as `ng-controller` in the template of the route. This second instantiation of the controller is what fails.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't find an explanation anywhere else.

Comment: I was going crazy, the error message should be more explanatory

Answer (score 8):

You can get resolved data in your controller using $route service.

Please see demo here http://plnkr.co/edit/2oID3G0QStTOGEPPLQ3h?p=preview

so in your example it going to looks like below:

```
.when('/banner1', {
    templateUrl: 'banner1.php',
    controller: 'ModuleController',
    resolve: {
      properties: function() {
        return { name: 'Banner', slug: 'banner' };
      }
    }
  })
```

and in controller :

```
app.controller('ModuleController', ['$http', '$route',
  function($http, $route) {
    var module = this;

   //get resolved properties
    module.properties = $route.current.locals.properties;

    if (module.properties.slug.length) {
      $http.get(module.properties.slug + '.php').success(function(data) {
        module.list = data;
      });
    }
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
resolve : {
    properties : ['projects', 'user', function (projects, user) {
        return user.getData().then(function () {
            return projects.getData();
        });
    }]
}
```

Comment: Add some explanation

Comment: Please provide more details to your answer as this post has been found in low quality post. Code only and 'try this' answers are discouraged as it doesn't provide any searchable content and why people should 'try this'.

Answer (score 0):

Using Dependency Injection with ng-route
try this;

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute", "localytics.directives"]);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider',function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "/TimeLine.html",
            controller: "MainCtrl"
        })    
        .when("/AddOrEditOccasion", {
            templateUrl: "/Html/GiftWhiz/AddOrEditOccasion.html",
            controller: "AddOrEditOccasionCtrl"
        })
        .when("/OccasionStart", {
            templateUrl: "/OccasionStart.html",
            controller: "OccasionStartCtrl"
        })        
}]);


myApp.controller("MainCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', '$location', function ($scope, $http, $location) {

   //your codes

}]);
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.