# Passing data from ngRoute resolve to controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-services, ngroute

I have an app where I am using ngRoute to generate an SPA. I don't want to load the view until I have finished fetching the data from the DB. The below works but I am unable to pass the return data to my controller.

**Angular Service:**

```
angular.module('routeService',[])

.factory('dataFetch', function($http, $q){

var deferred = $q.defer();
var factory = {}

factory.getProposals = function(){


    return $http.get('urlHere')
        .then(function(response){
            //promise is fulfilled
            deferred.resolve(response.data);

            console.log("readched the bio service!" + response.data);

            //promise is returned
           // return deferred.promise;
            return response.data;

        }, function(response){
            deferred.reject(response);

            //promise is returned
            return deferred.promise;
        });};


      return factory;

   });
```

**Angular Controller:**

```
var login = angular.module('login', ['ngRoute', 'routeService'])

 // configure our routes
login.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        // route for the home page

        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/overview.html',
            controller: 'login',
            resolve: {
                myDta: function(dataFetch){
                    return dataFetch.getProposals();
                }
            }

        })

});

login.controller('login', function($scope, myDta){

   $scope.prop = myDta

})
```

**I get the following error:**

`Unknown provider: myDtaProvider <- myDta <- login`

Comment: Besides some bad practice of promises I see no real problem with your code. Did you include `routeService.js` in your `index.html` file?

Comment: @MuliYulzary Can you explain the bad practice?

Answer (score 0):

### Erroneous Use of `ng-controller='login'`

> I get the following error:
>
> ```
> Unknown provider: myDtaProvider <- myDta <- login
> ```

The error message means that the `login` controller is being instantiated from an `ng-controller` directive somewhere. When the `ngRoute` services instantiates a controller, it will inject resolves as a **local**. The `ng-controller` directive does not have access to the resolves from a router.

**From another StackOverflow Answer:<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28997456/angularjs-how-to-inject-dependency-from-resolve-routeprovider/29021432#29021432)</sup>**

> `ngRoute` supports injection of resolved variables to the controller, which is useful for cross-cutting concerns of the app, like authentication or configuration of the app.
>
> The downside is that the controller can only be instantiated with these parameters available to be injected, which means that either you instantiate your controller manually (with `$controller`), which almost never the case, or with `ngRoute` with resolve. What you cannot do with such a controller is instantiate it with `ng-controller` or in any other location where the injected parameters are not available.
>
> This error indicates that in addition to having defined the controller on the route, you also have the controller defined as `ng-controller` in the template of the route. This second instantiation of the controller is what fails.

-- [StackOver: How to inject dependency from resolve routeProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28997456/angularjs-how-to-inject-dependency-from-resolve-routeprovider/29021432#29021432)

---

### Deferred Anti-Pattern<sup>[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750207/is-this-a-deferred-antipattern)</sup>

The `dataFetch` service erroneously implements a classic [deferred anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750207/is-this-a-deferred-antipattern). The `$http` service already returns a promise. There is no need to manufacture a promise with `$q.defer()`. Instead **chain** and return from the `$http` promise.

```
angular.module('routeService',[])

.factory('dataFetch', function($http, $q){

    //var deferred = $q.defer();
    var factory = {}
    
    factory.getProposals = function(){

        return $http.get('urlHere')
            .then(function onSuccess(response){    
                console.log("readched the bio service!" + response.data);
                //return to chain data
                return response.data;
    
            }, function onReject(errorResponse){
                //throw to chain rejection
                throw errorResponse;
            });
    };

    return factory;

});
```

For more information, see [StackOverflow: Is this a “Deferred Antipattern”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750207/is-this-a-deferred-antipattern)

Answer (score -2):

You can use `$route` service to access resolved values as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29021432/2509344).
Further your factory has very annoying things. You are using a global promise and returning promise in case of error. That is totally wrong. Correct way to use promise is

```
angular.module('routeService',[])
   .factory('dataFetch', function($http, $q) {
       var factory = {}
       factory.getProposals = function() {

          var deferred = $q.defer();
          $http.get('urlHere')
             .then(function(response) {
                 // Do what else you want to do
                 deferred.resolve(response.data);
             }, function(response) {
                 // Do what else you want to do
                 deferred.reject(response);
             });

          return deferred.promise;
       };

       return factory;
   });
```

And add dependency to resolve data in routes like this

```
 $routeProvider

    // route for the home page

    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: '/overview.html',
        controller: 'login',
        resolve: {
            myDta: function(dataFetch){
                return dataFetch.getProposals();
            }
        }

    })
```

You can access `myDep` in `login` controller as followed:

```
 login.controller('login', function($scope, $route) {
    $scope.myDta = $route.current.locals.myDta;
 });
```

Here is the working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/WSJk8dhXv1Fvv4yaGf5n?p=preview

Comment: This is not the angular way to resolve data before controller load.

Comment: @MuliYulzary I'm just accessing resolved data using `$routes` services as direct dependency is failing. What's non-angular here ??

Comment: This seems okay to me. Can you explain whats not "the angular way" in this?

Comment: Direct dependency should work. There's something else here. Also misuse of the q service but that's not a big deal